# Received error message with npm run protractor config file which worked perfectly previously

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I am creating my 1st protractor framework and I am trying run a sample test  locally within my project. I can update and start webdriver fine. No issues at all.  Super confused where I went wrong!

I got to project level and performed the command

```
npm run protractor
```

I got the following message from my mac terminal

```
Jacquelines-MacBook-Air:JSworkspace jacquelinegeorge$ cd LocatorTraining
Jacquelines-MacBook-Air:LocatorTraining jacquelinegeorge$ npm run protractor

> LocatorTraining@ protractor /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining
> protractor configurations.js

[11:12:24] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:12:24] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
F

Failures:
1) protractor page Object  training encountered a declaration exception
  Message:
    ReferenceError: datadrive is not defined
  Stack:
    ReferenceError: datadrive is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/data.js:10:13)
        at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/PageObjectLocator1.js:3:9)
  Message:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
      (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
      (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
        at Window.maximize (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1686:25)
        at onPrepare (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/configurations.js:10:37)
        at q_1.Promise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/util.js:46:49)
        at Function.promise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:682:9)
        at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/util.js:38:16)
        at plugins_.onPrepare.then (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:98:27)
        at _fulfilled (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.136 seconds

[11:12:27] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:12:27] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[11:12:27] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[11:12:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! LocatorTraining@ protractor: `protractor configurations.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the LocatorTraining@ protractor script 'protractor configurations.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the LocatorTraining package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor configurations.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs LocatorTraining
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls LocatorTraining
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/npm-debug.log
```

So I checked the configurations.js file which looks like (that's the correct Spec.js file that I am testing):

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['PageObjectLocator1.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
     //logs
     //command for non angular web site

     //reporting
     //site Url???


  }
}
```

Then I went to the run configurations and cli.js in the project

[image]

so I checked my Spec file  I had no errors.

```
describe('protractor page Object  training',function(){
    var obj= require("./PageObjectDemo.js");
    var d= require("./data.js");

    beforeEach(function() {
        obj.geturl();//the url on your test page is a method

      });


    it('Perform Simple Calculation ',function(){
    // write your code here!!!

        obj.firstnumber.sendKeys(d.datadrive.firstinput);//page of object properties
        obj.secondnumber.sendKeys(d.datadrive.secondinput);//page object properties

        obj.gobutton.click();


      //Jasmine Attribute Syntax toBe. Jasmine takes care of the promise 'resolve'internally

        expect(obj.result.getText()).toBe(d.datadrive.result);      
        //this confirm printout in console.

   obj.result.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log(text) 
     }) //end of console log message           


    })//end of it block

    afterEach(function () {
       console.log("If you can see this, test is completed. Well Done!!");
    });
```

So I checked the data spec file :

```
module.exports.datadrive= 
    {
    firstinput:"3",
    secondinput:"5",
    result: "8"


    }

console.log(datadrive.result);
```

Following Yong suggestion, I updated to:

```
exports.datadrive = {
firstinput:"3",
secondinput:"5",
result: "8"
```

}

Got the following result:

```
[17:16:06] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[17:16:06] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[17:16:06] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[17:16:06] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! LocatorTraining@ protractor: `protractor configurations.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the LocatorTraining@ protractor script 'protractor configurations.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the LocatorTraining package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor configurations.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs LocatorTraining
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls LocatorTraining
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/npm-debug.log
```

OK, on saturday I updated my node.js ( installed updated node.js globally, however I run my `npm run protractor` a local project level.  Did do something wrong doing that?) and ran the Spec file again.  Got the following message (sigh).  I really don't know what I did wrong. I'm utterly confused.

```
Failures:
1) protractor page Object  training Perform Simple Calculation 
  Message:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
      (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
      (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.manage().window().maximize()
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
        at Window.maximize (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1686:25)
        at onPrepare (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/configurations.js:10:37)
        at q_1.Promise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/util.js:46:49)
        at Function.promise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:682:9)
        at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/util.js:38:16)
        at plugins_.onPrepare.then (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:98:27)
        at _fulfilled (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
  Message:
    Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
  Stack:
    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
        at runWaitForAngularScript.then (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:463:23)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
        at /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:459:27)
        at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:91:29)
        at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:831:22)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/PageObjectLocator1.js:14:19)
        at /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1077:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2505:12)
        at schedulerExecute (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
    From: Task: Run it("Perform Simple Calculation ") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at process.emit (events.js:188:7)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/PageObjectLocator1.js:11:2)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/PageObjectLocator1.js:1:63)
        at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.186 seconds

[12:40:08] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:40:08] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[12:40:08] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[12:40:08] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! LocatorTraining@ protractor: `protractor configurations.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the LocatorTraining@ protractor script 'protractor configurations.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the LocatorTraining package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor configurations.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs LocatorTraining
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls LocatorTraining
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/npm-debug.log
Jacquelines-MacBook-Air:LocatorTraining jacquelinegeorge$
```

Comment: Seems you did not give the entire output of  `npm run protractor` after you fixed the wrong in `data.js`. Please show the entire output.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong comes from your `data.js` , try change as following:

```
exports.datadrive = {
    firstinput:"3",
    secondinput:"5",
    result: "8"
}
```

Comment: thank you. I  just updated the question because I got another error message.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  I found the root cause of my problem.  I noticed  the error messages they kept mentioning  `"protractor":  + my config.js file.`

So I decided to  reconfigure this part of my package.json file.

note: I had already updated my node.js on my machine [using this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9gehlXhS6U)

I went into the **.bin folder** (I'm a mac user so  pressed `shift+cmd+.`  to reveal this hidden folder)  and dragged n dropped the location of the protractor command file into  my  package.json file.

then I linked it to the configurations.js file ensuring the spelling was correct.

Pressed `shift+cmd+.`again to hide the .bin folder

Saved the updated package.json file

opened a terminal and went to project at local level using cd and ls commands

ran `npm run start` to start protractor servers

ran `npm run protractor` to run test

TEST RAN PERFECTLY!!!!!